# Comparing two lists item by item

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, if-statement, for-loop

I have 2 lists and I want to compare these lists item-by-item.
For example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,1]
for i in a:
    if i in b:
        pass # do something
    else:
        pass # do something else instead
```

I find this implementation a bit trivial.

I would like to know other ways of efficiently achieving the task.
(Efficiency implies either time complexity or space complexity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sets to find the common elements of `a` and `b`.

```
common_elements = set(a) & set(b)
for item in a:
    if item in common_elements:
        pass # do something 
    else: 
        pass # do something else instead
```

Set construction is O(N) in the average case, and set membership testing is O(1), making this whole algorithm O(N) in total. In comparison, membership testing for lists is O(N), so your original algorithm is O(N^2).

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your solution but I cannot convert the lists into sets. I have to work with lists only

Comment: @KshitijSaraogi: Why can't you use sets? Are you using a _really_ old version of Python? If you can't use sets, then your stuck with an O(n^2) algorithm... unless you implement your own hash table, which would be slow running at Python speed instead of the C speed you get from using a Python set.

Comment: @PM2Ring I am working with lists of some objects and I want to use the lists at several other places. Moreover, I, personally dont prefer type casting for an operation.

Comment: Just to be clear, the lists aren't being "converted" into sets in the sense that `a` and `b` are no longer lists. Creating `common_elements` has no effect on a and b; they are the same type and have the same contents as they did before that line executed.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

We can use a temporary array to check whether each element of `a` is present in `b` or not. This size of this array should be greater than the maximum element that can be present in both lists (I googled that the maximum size of Python list in 32-bit system is **536,870,912**, so this method will work in normal cases). This temporary list `temp_b` will initially have each element equal to zero. Now, for all integers present in list b, we will initialise the value at that index to 1, indicating that this element is present in b. After this all we have to do is: for each element `i` in `a`, check whether `temp_b[i] == 1`? If yes, then the element is present, else not.

Note that to check whether the frequency of each element in `a` also matches in `b`, we will have to modify this code. The complexity will be linear to the size of the array.

```
a = [2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 8, 9]
b = [1, 3, 6, 7, 4, 3, 0]

temp_b = [0]*20

for i in b:
    temp_b[i] = 1

#to check whether each element of a is present in b or not
for i in a:
    if temp_b[i] == 1:
        #element is present
        print "present"
    else:
        #element is not present
        print "not present"
```

Edit: This method will work only for positive integers.

Comment: What if `a` is `[1,2,3,4]` and `b` is `[1,2,3]`? Won't this cause an `IndexError`? And what if `a` is `[1,2,3,4]` and `b` is `[0,1,2,3]`? Won't this say there are zero matches, when there are actually three?

Comment: Yes you are right, maybe I judged your problem only on the basis of the values that were given.

Answer (score 0):

```
a, b = [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1]
for i in map(lambda i:i in b,a):
    if i == True:
        # do someting
    else:
        # do other
```

Comment: You should try to explain your solution instead of just posting code.

Comment: @Ketul It would be really helpful if you can explain your answer

Comment: This code doesn't give you access to the current element of `a` that's in `b`, so its usefulness is extremely limited. Slightly better would be `for v, flag in map(lambda i:(i, i in b), a):` `if flag: #do stuff with v` etc.